# Generalisation of spanning tree in simplex

Tags: linear-algebra, simplex, polytopes

Let $\Delta$ be some $n$-simplex. Note that if some $n-1$-dimensional affine hyperplane $U$ intersects $\Delta$, then $U$ separates the vertices of $\Delta$. Therefore, if $T$ is some spanning tree of the vertices then $U$ must intersect $T$. It follows that a sufficient condition for $U$ not intersecting $\Delta$ is $U$ not intersecting $T$. (With spanning tree I mean a union of edges that contains no triangles such that every vertex belongs to one of the edges).

Now suppose that $U$ is $n-k$-dimensional. Then can we find some minimal family $T$ of $k$-faces of $\Delta$ such that $U$ does not intersect $\Delta$ if and only if $U$ does not intersect $T$? I find this a difficult problem.

Comment: Well, $k=1$ is simple, like you said. $k=n-1$ is also simple: $T$ will include all faces but one. And the general case looks hard indeed.

Comment: Good point! I have a frank question: do you think this question is at all interesting? Or does it not get attention because it is so hard?

Comment: It is not clear if any progress can be made. (Then again, I'm not exactly qualified to assess this.) So yes, it is interesting, but hard, and hence will be probably left as it is. Math is full of dead ends, after all.

Comment: @IAnemaet I consider this question interesting. And I see no a priori reason for why it should be *too* hard (or a dead end). If you receive no answer I think this is a nice fit for MathOverflow too.